# Style textarea content with the same style as any other element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I would like to dynamically insert textareas into different parts of my site and have the styling of the text in the textarea match the style of the normal text in that element. Is it possible to do this with JavaScript? I thought that perhaps I could loop through all the `obj.style` properties and just apply them to the textarea.

For example, the font used in the textarea's on stackoverflow is a 10px(?) mono-spaced font while the final content text looks like 14px Arial.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is through a CSS class. Either change the style of all textareas with `textarea { /* CSS */ }` or use a special class for them like `textarea.dynamicallyInserted { /* CSS */ }` with `<textarea class="dynamicallyInserted"></textarea>`

Comment: But since the textareas are inserted into random elements - I won't have any idea what the styles of that element are.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want your style to use the same style as its parent's style, try using `font-family:inherit;` for example.

Comment: +1 Ah, that might work! I could set every style as inherit assuming the browser would treat it correctly. I would just have to guess about which styles would need to be inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, you can enumerate as many css properties as you want and set them on the element you're adding:

```
function addTextArea(targetId) {
    $('#' + targetId).add('textarea')
        .css('font-family', $('#' + targetId).css('font-family'))
        .css('font-size', $('#' + targetId).css('font-size')); //etc...
}
```